# need to get ui grid column data alone based on column name from external dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using Ui grid in my angularjs application. My requirement is I have an  external dropdow (out side of the ui grid) which contains all the column names of the ui grid. Now when I select any particular column name, I need to get only that column data in an array. Is there any simple way of achieving it?

For example, in this case, http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/217_column_moving, if I select 'name' in my external drop down then I need to get ['Sandoval Mclean', 'Nieves Mack', ...], similarly if I select 'email', then I need to get ['
sandovalmclean@zolavo.com', 'nievesmack@oulu.com', ... ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ajjOg9Y0vpq5FOiGHTPb?p=preview)

Quite simple really, just build your dropdown off your columnDefs so that you know you get valid object properties and iterate them on dropdown change:

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-model="selectedColumn" 
  ng-options="opt.name as opt.name for opt in gridOptions.columnDefs"
  ng-change="onColSelect()"></select>

<ol>
  <li ng-repeat="obj in myData track by $index">{{obj}}</li>
</ol>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.onColSelect = function (){
     $scope.myData = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.gridOptions.data, function (row, key) {
      $scope.myData.push(row[$scope.selectedColumn]);         
});
```